# PyQt5 Changing button colors too often causes 'freeze' until I refresh screen

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I have a grid (22x16) of QPushButtons that you select source and destination locations for a pathing algorithm. When it runs, I color the push buttons to show a path from the source to the destination. This involves turning next pad in the path to a color and changing the previous pad to the default color. So this would look like you a game of snake where a block is moving across the grid.

What happens after I do about 30-40 color changes, the color changing stops, almost like the screen is frozen. If I click on a QWidget or minimize/maximize the screen, it works again. The code is still running in the background and things are 'moving' but its just not displaying anymore.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? is this a bug in pyqt5?

Comment: Without knowing *how* you change those colors, nobody would be able to answer you. Please provide a [mre]. (Btw, you're not using threading to do that, are you?)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.